# Extension to upgrade Target Framework in VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Is there a Visual Studio 2012 extension or other utility, which can change the target .Net framework version for all the projects in a solution?

I am aware of Scott Dorman's Visual Studio script, however that script will not work in Visual Studio 2012, as Microsoft discontinued VS scripts in favor of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This might just solve your problem.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13

Please note this does not take care of managed C++ projects. 
You may need manually change the target framework

Changing the Target .NET Framework for C++/CLI

To change the version of the .NET Framework for C++/CLI projects

1. Right click on project in Solution Explorer and click Unload project
2. Right click on unloaded project in Solution Explorer and select Edit `<projectname>.vcxproj`
3. In project XML file locate node `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">`
4. In that node locate node `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` (if the node cannot be found, add it)
5. Inner text of the node defines target framework. It can be v2.0,v3.0, v3.5, v4.0 or v4.5
6. Save vcxproj file and close it
7. Right click on unloaded project in Solution Explorer and click Reload Project

Example:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Hope this helps. 
-manirup